# Angular 4 + Redux (or ngrx/store) folder and file structure

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx

Ref to Angular official site's style guile of file structure:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#04-06

If I would like to implement Redux (or ngrx/store) to my new Angular 4 project, would it be better to structure my application in this way?

```
    project root

    ├── src/
    │   ├── app/
    │   │  ├──stores/
    │   │  │  ├── heros/
    │   │  │  │  ├── heros.actions.ts|reducer|effects|store.ts
    │   │  │  │ 
    │   │  │  │── ..../
    │   │  │  │  ├── .....
    │   │  │  
    │   │  ├── containers/
    │   │  │  ├── heros/
    │   │  │  │  ├── heros.component.ts|html|css|spec.ts
    │   │  │  │  │  └── ......
    │   │  │  
    │   │  │
    │   │  ├── components/
    │   │  │  ├── hero-list/
    │   │  │  │  │  ├── hero-list.component.ts|html|css|spec.ts
    │   │  │  │  │  └── .......
    │   │  │  ├── ....

I have been using second structure but as my app grows, it was getting difficult to maintain, and then I refactored the structure in this way, the plus point of this structure is, if in future you decide to remove or edit ngrx all you need to do is remove or edit the stores folder.

Note:

- containers folder hold my smart components

- components folder hold my dumb components
```

Or follow ngrx/store's example (https://github.com/ngrx/example-app), to structure the application in this way?

```
    project root
    ├── src/
    │   ├── app/
    │   │  ├── actions/
    │   │  │  ├── hero.js
    │   │  │  ├── hero-list.js
    │   │  │  └── ......
    │   │  ├── reducers/
    │   │  │  ├── hero.js
    │   │  │  ├── hero-list.js
    │   │  │  └── ......
    │   │  ├── components/
    │   │  │  ├── heros/
    │   │  │  │  ├── hero/
    │   │  │  │  │  ├── hero-list.component.ts|html|css|spec.ts
    │   │  │  │  │  └── ......
    │   │  │  │  ├── hero-list/
    │   │  │  │  │  ├── hero-list.component.ts|html|css|spec.ts
    │   │  │  │  │  └── ......
    │   │  │  ├── ......
```

Is there any other better structure?

Comment: Either use app/ or src/ as the app root folder... (src/app doesn't make sense unless you have like src/app2, src/app3, and in that case, is separate those apps into separate repos)

Comment: I'd do it the first way, but it's just personal preference/opinion. Hence the close vote.

Comment: In the future, feature modules will be able to add their own reducers.  For this reason, I have a dir in each module for it's store `/app/feature/store`, and it contains `feature.actions.ts`, `feature.reducer.ts`, and `feature.selectors.ts`

Comment: You may want to take a look to a github repo I've made to show how I like to do that : https://github.com/maxime1992/angular-ngrx-starter

Answer (score 4):

project root

```
├── src/
│   ├── app/
│   │  ├──stores/
│   │  │  ├── heros/
│   │  │  │  ├── heros.actions.ts|reducer|effects|store.ts
│   │  │  │ 
│   │  │  │── ..../
│   │  │  │  ├── .....
│   │  │  
│   │  ├── containers/
│   │  │  ├── heros/
│   │  │  │  ├── heros.component.ts|html|css|spec.ts
│   │  │  │  │  └── ......
│   │  │  
│   │  │
│   │  ├── components/
│   │  │  ├── hero-list/
│   │  │  │  │  ├── hero-list.component.ts|html|css|spec.ts
│   │  │  │  │  └── .......
│   │  │  ├── ....
```

I have been using second structure but as my app grows, it was getting difficult to maintain, and then I refactored the structure in this way, the plus point of this structure is, if in future you decide to remove or edit ngrx all you need to do is remove or edit the stores folder.

Note:

- containers folder hold my smart components
- components folder hold my dumb components

Comment: heros.store.ts is the model?

Comment: What will be the model (entity, interface) here?